# How can I get the id from select tag as params?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a little bit confused in how can this params work. For example I trying to create a collections of users with select tag in index page like this:

users/index.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag "user", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "name")%>

<%= link_to "new", new_user_book_path(params[:user]) %>
```

I have a dropdown with a list of users, and I have a button which links to books/new page. How can I pass the `user id` which I have selected in the dropdown to the 'new_user_book_path`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write some javascript for it.

```
<%= select_tag "user", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "name"), {id: "select_users" } %>
<!-- If you don't pass id attribute, the default id will be 'user' by convention -->

<%= link_to "New", new_user_book_path(@users.first.id), id: "btn_book", data: { book_path: new_user_book_path } %>
```

Which will look something like this when converted to plain html

```
<select name="user" id="select_users">
  <option value="1">User1</option>
  <option value="2">User2</option>
</select>

<a id="btn_book" data-book-path="book/new" href="books/new/1">New</a>
```

Notice we're we have the path setup with the first user, so if nothing is selected from the select dropdown, the first user will be passed to params. Now we'll write some script to update the path with the selected user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select_users").on('change', function(){
    var user = $(this).val();
    var path = $("#btn_book").attr("data-book-path");
    $("#btn_book").attr('href', path + "/" + user);
    //#btn_book is the id of our link, where we'll change its href to the selected user
  });
});
```

I'm assuming the conventional code, paths and other things might change. Adjust according to your needs. Hope this helps.